# How to find Network enable status in android?

Tags: android

Is there possible to find internet enable using intent in broadcast receiver in android pls help me? I want exactly background process when app is not open i want to detect network status

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this below code,

```
public class ConnectionAvailable extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();
    boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (!is3g && !isWifi) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        if ((intent.getAction() != null)
                && (intent.getAction()
                        .equals("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"))) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
        }
    }
}
}
```

This might help you out..

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
 }
```

Comment: i want to check when app will minimize

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
```

Comment: i want to check when app will minimize

Comment: you mean you want to check when the app is running in background?

Comment: s exactly i need to check background

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
             ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
             if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null) {
                   for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                          return true;
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
             return false;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;}
   and add this permission
```

call this method and add this permission in your manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: i know to check network status when app will running my question is how to detect network status when app will minimize (background process)