# fastest way to check internet access in android

Tags: android, wifi, httpurlconnection

I am building an app that helps configuring WIFI settings on Android and I need the fastest way to check for a working internet connection.
Working connection - not only WIFI connected!

I'm using this code

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                                final HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
                                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                                        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3 * 1000);
                                        urlc.connect();

                                        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) { // Good response



                                        } else { 
                                        //bad   

                                        }
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                         //bad
                                    }
```

but it takes a long time to get a response, about 20 seconds (even though timeout is 3 seconds?).
Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: goto this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889750/how-to-find-network-enable-status-in-android/12890037#12890037

Comment: @user1591982 Did my answer help in any way?

Comment: No, sorry. Same result. But thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: @user1591982 What errors do you get, if any? I've tested this code sideways and backwards :-) and it catches all cases so far. (android 4.x)

Comment: No errors, but if there is no internet access, it takes half a minute to throw an exception, even though timeout is set to 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, perhaps it would work better if you also added `urlc.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT);`

Below is the code I'm using and it has so far catched various scenarios of WiFi/Mobile connection but no Internet and so on.

```
public boolean isNetworksAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager mConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (mConnMgr != null)  {
        NetworkInfo[] mNetInfo = mConnMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (mNetInfo != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mNetInfo.length; i++) {
                if (mNetInfo[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What this code does is loop thru all the Network states to make sure it finds a CONNECTED state, only then is `isNetworksAvailable()`

In `isInternetConnected` we check if we can make a simple HTTP URL Connection.

```
public boolean isInternetConnected(String mUrl) {
    final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    if (isNetworksAvailable()) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection mURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(mUrl).openConnection());
            mURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "ConnectionTest");
            mURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            mURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            mURLConnection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            mURLConnection.connect();
            return (mURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("isInternetConnected", "Exception occured while checking for Internet connection: ", ioe);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("isInternetConnected", "Not connected to WiFi/Mobile and no Internet available.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code should be used in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or otherwise you need to use it with the following code, for example in `onCreate()` (But it is highly recommended to use an AsyncTask instead of doing networking on the UI thread)

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Test if connected to Internet:

```
if (isInternetConnected("http://www.google.com")) {
    showToast("Internet connected");
} else {
    showToast("No connection to the Internet!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use below method before you make server call :

```
public static boolean isOnline() {

    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) Const.CONTEXT
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm != null) {
            return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: if it returns true, the device has access to the internet?

Comment: it returns true even when there is no Internet access

Comment: this is well tested code but make sure what you are try to access that might be not available or not also,make sure in my code above Const.Context is you context should you used your context.

Comment: It says connected as long as the device is connected to a wireless network, and I need it to check if there is an access to the WWW

Comment: @Bhavdip Pathar
This code doesn't check if the device is connected to the Internet, ONLY if it is connected to a Network, like UMTS or WiFi. Read the API docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html